# How do I display Date time value as Specific Text

Tags: php, html

I have dates stored in the following format: `2022-08-09 02:36:18`

I would like to Display this information as: Aug 9th, 2022 2:36am

I have tried: `$result = $date->format('M jS, Y');` with this but not worked.

Trying this format causes my date to disappear from the page.  What am I missing here?

**CSS**

```
.posttime {
    height: auto;
    width: auto;
    margin: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
    font-size: 15px;
    font-weight: normal;
    font-family: Arial Narrow Bold;
    position: absolute;
    top: 20px;
    right: 20px;
}
```

**PHP**

```
echo '
                    <Div class="postBox">
                        <img class="postprofilepicture" src="../profilepictures/'.$ProfilePicture.'">
                        <p class="postusername">'.$UserName.'<p>
                        <p class="posttime">'.date_format($Date,"M jS, Y h:i A").'<p>
                        <p>'.$Text.'<p>
                    </div>
                    <br>
                ';
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple do by this:

```
$date = "2022-08-09 02:36:18";
echo date('M jS,Y h:i A',strtotime($date));
```

Answer (score 1):

Try `$result = date_format($date,"M jS, Y h:ia")`. Checking `date_format()` function is using `date_format(object, format)` as the correct syntax.

Either that or youre using `'` instead of `"`. Does this work?

Refer to this [link](https://www.w3schools.com/php/func_date_date_format.asp).

Comment: Now I'm trying: 
echo '
<p class="posttime">'.date_format($Date,"M jS, Y h:i A").'<p>
';

It's still disappearing

Answer (score 1):

You can try with this-

```
<?php
 $date=date_create("2022-08-09 02:36:18");
 echo date_format($date,"M jS, Y h:i A"); // Aug 9th, 2022 02:36 AM
?>
```

Comment: Edited my post above trying this, still not working :/

Comment: replace  `date_format($Date,"M jS, Y h:i A")`  to `date('M jS,Y H:i A',strtotime($Date));`